# Hibernate criteria by inner property

Tags: java, hibernate

Given following entities:

```
Order{id, List<Product> list}
Product{id, name, Status}
Status{id, name, endPoint}
```

The Order contains a list of products. Products are in different statuses. And Status has a property which defines whether that status is considered final or endPoint (regarding some workflows)

How would you create a hibernate criteria in which I can find those Orders which all its Products are in Status endPoint=true;

Comment: Read about `criteria.createAlias `

Comment: Yes it possible. It would be something like `list.id` at your criteria param as long as you complete with `createAlias` specified above.